# Test for a cell not being formulaically populated vs one with data sourced from a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that auto-populates column B to equal the cells in column A. Column C will be the cell in column A, one row down, but if the cell in column A of the same row and column A of the next row are the same, it wil be column A of two rows down.  Using this formula: `=IF(A5=A6,A7,A6)`.

Right now, it prints data in one of the cells when they only contain the formula. I dont understand why.The right column below, which has 2 indigo, 
is an example of the problem, with 'empty' where the cells are not populated, they have a blank pick list.

..  A ....... B....        . C

2 red      .... red   .  orange

3   orange orange  yellow

4  yellow yellow  green

5 green  green   blue

6 blue.. blue... 0

7 empty .    0....       indigo

8 empty    ..  0 ....indigo

```
9 indigo    indigo violet
```

.

---

I don't mind the 0 being displayed, but the 3rd column up, right cell, is printing indigo, when it shouldn't be. The columns above that work fine. 
NOTE: The cell in column C, violet, has a slightly different formula, if the
first cell matches the cell below, it sets it to the first data cell in column c, otherwise to the next cell in column A `=if(a8=a9,a2,a9)`
What I need to see to reduce the risk of human error, is have either a zero, or
nothing displayed in the cell which is showing the first indigo in column c.

Comment: Please include your column and row numbers so the placement of data has context.

Comment: The two indigos "appear" to be in a column D which has not been mentioned. I think your alignment is off. And it is printing indigo correctly according to the formula.

Comment: you should improve your explanation with examples of both correct and uncorrect outputs to thoroughly cover the logic you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is working correctly. The **IF** function evaluates a condition and returns either the `True` or `False` statement depending on the evaluation. Your condition is evaluating `A5=A6` i.e. current cell equals cell above.

Row 9 `Blue` and `Empty` are not equal so you get `0` as this is what the empty cell `A10` returns

Row 10 `Empty` and `Empty` are equal so `A12` returned which is `indigo`

Row 11 `Empty` and `Indigo` are not equal so `A12` returned which is `indigo`.

Instead change your test conditions to handle `blank` cells try:

Column B (To get rid of zeroes)

```
=IF(A5="","",A5)
```

Column C

Try variations on the following:

```
=IF(OR(A5="",A6=""), "", IF(A5=A6,A7,A6))
```

This part: `OR(A5="",A6="")` is handling all combinations of blank comparisons i.e. current cell is blank, cell above is blank, both are blank.

Switch these out with **ISBLANK** function for `empty` cells:

Column  B

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(A5),"",A5)
```

Column C

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A5),ISBLANK(A6)), "", IF(A5=A6,A7,A6))
```

If you want to handle blank/empty cases differently then consider also using other logic operators e.g. `AND` operator in a test with `AND(ISBLANK(A5),ISBLANK(A6))` if only where both blank, for example. In the above example, the `OR` operator will cover this because I was catering for any occurrence of a blank/empty in current or cell above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to add a closing paren in the first formula, but aside from that, everything worked fine.

Comment: Edited to reflect this. Apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize. I figure you missed a character with cp/paste. As I said you've solved my problem. I'm actually, finally finished with my template. Thanks again.

Comment: I did upvote, but since I have such a low rep, and getting lower thanks to downvotes for this question, the upvote wasnt reflected on the answer.

Comment: That was my fault. The check was grayed out. Thanks again.